# Im not able to send the posted hidden value to database using code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can print the hidden posted value properly but when i submit to database value is shown as zero in database table .im posting a integer value and int is the datatype given in database.

```
$array = array(
    "unit_id"=>$this->input->post("unit_id"),
    "head_id"=>$this->input->post("unit_head_id"),
    );

    $this->db->insert('request', $array);
```

Comment: Are you sure the int is posted? Is the hidden input inside the form + does the input field have a name? Please show the generated HTMl code.

Comment: Input have the same name and also i printed it on the model they are numbers.

Comment: If you are sure the $array has values, maybe there is an inconsistency in the names (keys) in the array vs columns in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Its not issue of hidden fields

in controller you have to match correct key value for the fields, please cross verify it

```
$array = array(
  "unit_id"=>$this->input->post("unit_id"),
  "head_id"=>$this->input->post("unit_head_id"),
);

$this->db->insert('request', $array);
```